# How can I serialize a custom object that has a Context as a private member using Gson?

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

I have an ArrayList of custom objects that I'm trying to store to disk as a JSON String using Gson. This works great for my objects that just contain basic types of data like Strings, but one class I have has a private member that stores the Activity's Context. When I try to serialize this class using Gson, I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.xxxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make method constructor accessible
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make method constructor accessible
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:336)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:101)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:83)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:49)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:106)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1.create(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:48)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:49)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:106)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:49)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:106)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:49)
                                                                    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(Refle
```

I'm guessing the issue is that there is a method inside Context that Gson can't access because it's protected or something similar. So is there a way I can serialize objects that contain other complex objects using Gson?

Here is a short code snippet that will produce the crash:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(this);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String myObjectJson = gson.toJson(myObject);
    }

    public class MyObject {

        private Context context;

        public MyObject(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Context` is not serializable. You should declare variable as `transient` for preventing it to be serialized. Of course you should assign it manually when deserializing.

```
public class MyObject {

    private transient Context context;

    // ... other fields here

    public MyObject() {
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

}
```

Comment: Even more than this-  if you did serialize it somehow, it wouldn't work as a valid Context on the other side of the serialization.  The OP is almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm not sure but it seems there's some kind of issue with Gson (see [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/648)). Removing Context from constructor parameters could maybe solve the issue in this situation.

Comment: @GabeSechan - I understand that it makes no sense to serialize a Context that will no longer be in use during deserialization. The issue is not that I need the Context (I could always set it manually, as suggested), but more that I already have a complex class embedded in a complex app, and I'm just trying to save myself from lots of refactoring if it's not needed. I just wasn't sure if there was any way to get Gson to deal with this sort of thing gracefully. If I have to just exclude the Context during serialization and set it manually, that's fine if it's the only way to deal with this.