# java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible

Tags: java, android, gson

I am using Gson version 2.8.2

I have used below code

```
public void saveObject(View view){
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String str = gson.toJson(view, View.class);
        editor.putString("text", str);
        editor.commit();
}
```

but I am getting an error like below

```
Process: com.example.amitsiddhpura.paperview, PID: 17252
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amitsiddhpura.paperview/com.example.amitsiddhpura.paperview.MainActivity}: **java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible**
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(AccessibleObject.java:131)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:115)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:101)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:83)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1.create(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:48)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
                                                                                         at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
                                                                                         at com.example.amitsiddhpura.paperview.MainActivity.saveObject(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                                         at com.example.amitsiddhpura.paperview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error trying to use GSON with own class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754923/error-trying-to-use-gson-with-own-class)

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to save View class which contains context, which cannot be serialised. 
[Read Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936441/how-can-i-serialize-a-custom-object-that-has-a-context-as-a-private-member-using)

Answer (score 0):

your first parameter view is wrong in toJson method .From document [Class GSON](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html). pass suitable parameter it will work

toJson(JsonElement jsonElement)

> Converts a tree of JsonElements into its equivalent JSON
>   representation.

void    toJson(JsonElement jsonElement, Appendable writer)

> Writes out the equivalent JSON for a tree of JsonElements.

void    toJson(JsonElement jsonElement, JsonWriter writer)

> Writes the JSON for jsonElement to writer.

String  toJson(Object src)

> This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json
>   representation.

void    toJson(Object src, Appendable writer)

> This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json
>   representation.

String  toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc)

> This method serializes the specified object, including those of
>   generic types, into its equivalent Json representation.

void    toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, Appendable writer)

> This method serializes the specified object, including those of
>   generic types, into its equivalent Json representation.

void    toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonWriter writer)

> Writes the JSON representation of src of type typeOfSrc to writer.

Comment: I have used String str = gson.toJson(view, View.class); not fromJson :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create companion object of that class and use it